# meaning of R, S, Da in kCGBlendMode values

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having trouble grasping the meaning of `R = 0`, `R = S`, `R = S*Da`, defined in `kCGBlendMode` values such as `kCGBlendModeClear`, `kCGBlendModeCopy`, `kCGBlendModeSourceIn`. So, to what do these symbols refer?

Comment: well there is also D and Sa..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R=0` means that the result color will just be 0, meaning it will be cleared.

`R=S` means the result color is the same as the source color

`R=S*Da` means the result is the source color times the alpha value of the destination

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGBlendMode) and scroll down you will see their meaning listed:

> The blend mode constants introduced in OS X v10.5 represent the Porter-Duff blend modes ([a little explanation how they work](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html)). The symbols in the equations for these blend modes are:
>
> - R is the premultiplied result
> - S is the source color, and includes alpha
> - D is the destination color, and includes alpha
> - Ra, Sa, and Da are the alpha components of R, S, and D

If you furthermore take a look at [Setting blend modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-BCIGICEF) you can see most of the blend modes applied and what their result may look like.